# Converting between relative RMS and dbFS

Tags: audio

I'm trying to replicate a method in a paper where the relative RMS level "was fixed to be +6dB more intense" than another sound. Unfortunately, the Python library I'm doing this processing in uses dbFS, and setting a gain of 6 barely makes a difference to the percieved loudness. Is there a method to switch between relative RMS and dBFS?

Comment: Did you look up what RMS and dBFS mean?

Comment: I think this question belongs to dsp.stackexchange as it makes reference to the use of a library.

Comment: When referring to levels, it is assumed that you use $dB$ (related to the "RMS level" you mention). The increase or decrease in $dB$ is the same irrespective of the underlying "$dB$ type". If you want to decrease by $6 ~ dB$ your RMS value you cut it in half (I assume you refer to voltage, or some other derived quantity). The same applies to the $dB_{FS}$, so if you want to make it $6 ~ dB$ "less" then you divide by $2$.